# How to rename .exe (executable) file of Window Store App?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, store

I edited a template of Window Store App and renamed everything in the app to my new App Name but I am unable to find a way to rename its .exe File inside visual studio. I tried searching and its not showing me any result in VS-2013 named "Shopping". How can I rename this .exe file?

[image: VS-2013 Search Results finding nothing]

[image: Screen Shot of Files in Debug Folder of the App]

Comment: This would be in the Project Properties pages.

Comment: Thanks Man It worked Fine.

Comment: I'm curious why "Find in files" didn't work. It should have searched your `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

The executable file name and default namespace is set in the project's properties pane.

[image]

All other aspects (display name, description) are set in the Package.appxmanifest.